# Chemical energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, rocket-science

A physics problem I am solving has a rocket which launches and releases a certain chemical energy $u$. What is chemical energy? How would I incoporate it into the equations of conservation of energy?

Thanks.

Comment: Just consider it as any other type of energy in the energy conservation law.

Comment: @Steeven so would you say u = delta E? Where E is the mechanical energy.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the origin or formula of an energy type in order to use it in the energy conservation law. You just need to know its amount; how much the energy type is *changing*.

The energy conservation laws simply states that **no energy ever appears or disappears**. So, all energy present before equals all energy present after any moment:

$$\sum E_1 = \sum E_2 $$

The sum of all energies can contain many different types, such as kinetic $K$, gravitational $U_g$, electrical $U_e$, thermal $E_{th}$, chemical $E_{ch}$ and what not:

$$K_1+U_{g1}+U_{e1}+E_{th1}+E_{ch1}+... = K_2+U_{g2}+U_{e2}+E_{th2}+E_{ch2}+...$$

Also, we might even add extra energy to the process, such as by work $W$ or heat $Q$. If we add such extra energies, then there is more energy *after* than *before*, so we must adjust our expression by subtracting the added extra amount:

$$K_1+U_{g1}+U_{e1}+E_{th1}+E_{ch1}+... = K_2+U_{g2}+U_{e2}+E_{th2}+E_{ch2}+...-W-Q$$

**This is the full version of the energy conservation law.**

All those that *don't* change are the same before and after, so they cancel out. Maybe the electrical and thermal energies as well as all other non-identified energies don't change, and maybe we don't add any energy as work or heat so that they are zero:

$$\require{cancel}K_1+U_{g1}+\cancel{U_{e1}}+\cancel{E_{th1}}+E_{ch1}+\cancel{...} = K_2+U_{g2}+\cancel{U_{e2}}+\cancel{E_{th2}}+E_{ch2}+\cancel{...}-\cancel W-\cancel Q \Leftrightarrow\\
K_1+U_{g1}+E_{ch1} = K_2+U_{g2}+E_{ch2}$$

And here you have it. Because kinetic and gravitational energies are called mechanical energy $E_m$, the change in chemical energy, which you call $u$, equals the change in mechanical energy: $$\underbrace{K_1+U_{g1}}_{E_{m1}}+E_{ch1} = \underbrace{K_2+U_{g2}}_{E_{m2}}+E_{ch2}\Leftrightarrow\\
E_{m1}+E_{ch1} =E_{m2}+E_{ch2}\Leftrightarrow\\
E_{m2}-E_{m1} =\underbrace{E_{ch1}-E_{ch2}}_u\Leftrightarrow\\
\Delta E_{m} =u$$

As long as you know the size of $u$, then this use of the energy conservation law is easy. It doesn't matter what the different energy types are or where they come from, as long as you know how much they change.

---

In general, chemical energy is for instance energy associated with atomic and molecular bonding. When a chemical reaction takes place, some energy trapped in the molecules may now be released. Also, chemical energy may cover energy associated with diffusion and drift of chemical substances, and in the case of fuel - which may be your case - it is often the term used for the gasses that are formed during combustion (such gasses expand and do work on their surroundings, which is what makes the rocket fly forward; this may be what your $u$ covers in this task). It is quite a broad term.